# MPI pass value to all the cores

Tags: c, mpi, broadcast

I code my MPI program using C. Assume I use 10 cores. I want to pass `glob` to all the other cores, but `glob` in the following code is executed by one of the cores, which is illegal and the code will be dead.

```
for ( i = 0; i < n_loc; i++ ) {   /*n_loc is the local number based on each core*/
    if ( a_loc[i] == glob ) {  /*a_loc is a local array based on each core*/
        glob += 1;
        MPI_Bcast ( &glob, 1, MPI_INT, MYID, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    }
}
```

So what can I do to solve this problem, the global variable is changed by one of the 10 cores but I want to inform the other 9 cores?

Comment: There is no such thing as onesided collectives in MPI. I do not know what you are trying to achieve, but it seems your program has an undefined behavior in parallel. Please post a [MCVE] so you can be advised on how to best move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that MPI communication always requires you to call the appropriate MPI function on all your ranks. `MPI_Bcast` is the correct function to use in this circumstance, but you need to call it on all ranks.  Check the documentation at https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Bcast.html and you will see that the "root" argument to MPI_Bcast determines which rank the value is copied from to all the others.

An example of correct MPI_Bcast usage:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "mpi.h"

int main(){
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int comm_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_size);
    int rank; // Get the number of the rank
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);  

    int my_data = rank; // Set mydata = rank -- will be different on all ranks
    for(int i=0; i < comm_size; i++){
        if(rank == i){
            printf("Rank %i: Value %i\n", rank, my_data);
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    // Communicate the value of my_data from rank 0 to all other ranks
    int root_rank = 0;
    if(rank == root_rank){
        printf("Broadcasting from rank %i:\n", root_rank);
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&my_data, 1, MPI_INT, root_rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // my_data is now 0 on all ranks
    for(int i=0; i < comm_size; i++){
        if(rank == i){
            printf("Rank %i: Value %i\n", rank, my_data);
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    return 0;
}
```